# tail --follow=name inside script starts as a separate process

Tags: shell-script, ps, background-process

I have a script that checks a log file and searches for a string, and it runs in the background with `&`.
When I `ps -ef | grep script.sh` and I kill that script, I can always see the `tail` and `grep` processes of the same script still alive.

another thing is that the process id of the `tail` is the `script.sh`'s process id minus 2 (i.e `script.sh` pid is 7002, `tail` pid is 7000 and `grep` pid is 7001.

1. Why do the commands inside `script.sh` start as their own service with father pid = 1?
2. How to efficiently kill the `script.sh` and all of the child processes it created?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that the script was finished with `&`

When I deleted the `&` from the script, and ran the command like so:

`nohup sudo script.sh &`

The `tail` and `grep` processes were under the main `script` pid :)